# Facebook OAuth 2.0 Javascript SDK authResponse

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade our app to use the newest OAuth 2.0 Javascript code.  In my app settings under "Migrations" I have everything enabled.  (OAuth Migration, Upgrade to Requests 2.0, etc)

After calling FB.init with: oauth: true.

Then calling FB.getLoginStatus (same for FB.login) and checking my response object I have a response.session but not a response.authResponse?  Anyone know of any settings I could have missed or what would cause the oauth FB calls not to return the authResponse like the documentation states?

response.status is there, but not response.authResponse.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like to me there is problem in your upgraded code.
To isolate the problem, create a new fb app, then use your upgraded code and see what happens.  For the app, simply set the canvas url / site url.  For all those "migration settings", just takes the default value.

With this, you can be sure that this is nothing caused by misconfigured of FB settings.

and if you get response.authResponse, then you can compare the current fb settings between these 2 fb apps.

Comment: Really simple code:

My fb.init parameters:
appId : api_key, // variable for api key 
channelUrl: channel_path, // variable to channel path
status: true, 
cookie : true,
xfbml: true,
aouth: true

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){ alert(response.authResponse); });

Comment: How about editing your question and adding the code there with proper formatting?

Comment: your problem is simply misspelling the param "oauth"

Answer (score 0):

As @Eddy Chan suggests in his comment, it sounds like the JS SDK isn't actually being instructed to use the new OAuth flow, probably due to a misspelling of the `oauth: true` parameter.